# How to run multiple es versions in same machine

Tags: elasticsearch

We have been using ES 1.7.5 from the very start and have not migrated to newer ES versions, it's been running great and we have been making it work. Now for some of the newer features, we want to use the latest ES, ES 8.9.0.
Please note, we would like to avoid migration in 1 go, we want to make sure we can do it step by step, which means for the time being both ES versions need to run locally for development.

How can I run both ES directly on my Windows laptop, strictly without using docker?
I am able to run both individually, but running both together seems to be clashing due to differences in JDK versions.

Answer (score 0):

1.Install two jdk

Say we have two version jdk 8 and jdk 17,first install jdk 8,you have a java 8 home path,then install jdk 17 to a different path,you have a java 17 home

2.Install two elasticsearch

Download and decompress es 1.7.5,Download and decompress es 8.9.0 to a different path.

3.Edit config file.

Open elasticsearch-1.7.5\config\elasticsearch.yml,edit the two lines to:

```
http.port: 9201
transport.tcp.port: 9301
```

Open elasticsearch-8.9.0\config\elasticsearch.yml,edit the line to:

```
http.port: 9202
transport.tcp.port: 9302
```

4.Create two script:
In elasticsearch-1.7.5\bin folder.create a run1.7.5.bat script file:

```
set JAVA_HOME=path\to\java8
elasticsearch.bat
```

In elasticsearch-8.9.0\bin folder.create a run8.9.0.bat script file:

```
set JAVA_HOME=path\to\java17
elasticsearch.bat
```

Then you can run run1.7.5.bat and run run8.9.0.bat at the same time,and you can visit localhost:9201 for es 1.7.5 and localhost:9202 for es 8.9.0

(If jdk8 is not suitable for es1.7.5,you can install a suitable one)